# Добавление строки в файл

Tags: java, android, файлы

Пытаюсь дозаписать в файл строку. Получается, что файл содержит только новую строку. Не понимаю, где ошибка?

```
 public void Write(String data) {
    File dataDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    ;
    /*
    dataDirectory = new File(dataDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_NAME);
    if (!dataDirectory.exists()) {
        dataDirectory.mkdir();
    }
    */

    Log.d("file", "mkdir is " + dataDirectory.exists());

    File file = new File(dataDirectory, "log.txt");
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        Log.d("file", "file creating is " + file.exists());

        Date date = new Date();

        //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data);
        stringBuilder.insert(0, date);
        fileWriter.append(stringBuilder.toString() + "\r\n");
        fileWriter.close();
        /*
        bufferedWriter.append(stringBuilder.toString()+"\r\n");;
        bufferedWriter.close();
        */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);` судя по документации https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы использовали базовый конструктор, который создает `FileWriter` без возможности дописать в конец файла.

Для того, чтобы он "дописывал" в конец файла, необходимо его инициализировать через другой конструктор:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true)
```

---

```
/**
 * Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second
 * argument is <code>true</code>, then bytes will be written to the end
 * of the file rather than the beginning.
 *
 * @param file  a File object to write to
 * @param     append    if <code>true</code>, then bytes will be written
 *                      to the end of the file rather than the beginning
 * @throws IOException  if the file exists but is a directory rather than
 *                  a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created,
 *                  or cannot be opened for any other reason
 * @since 1.4
 */
public FileWriter(File file, boolean append) throws IOException {
    super(new FileOutputStream(file, append));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void Write(String data) {
    File dataDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    File file = new File(dataDirectory, "log.txt");
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        Date date = new Date();
        // Вторым параметром передаётся указание на то, что в файл надо дописать
        // try-with-resource доступен с API 19+, можно без него, но с ним - проще
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
            // Если использовать StringBuilder, то использовать полностью
            String log_row = new StringBuilder()
                    .append(date)
                    .append(" ")
                    .append(data)
                    // Лучше использовать системную переменную новой строки
                    .append(System.lineSeparator())
                    .toString();
            fileWriter.append(log_row);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```